# How to check Exception for empty field in Android

Tags: java, android

I have this code in my app

```
 Button buttonConvertMilesToKm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvertMilesToKm);

        buttonConvertMilesToKm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            EditText textBoxMiles = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMiles);
            EditText textBoxKm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextKm);

            public void onClick(View v) {

                double vMiles = Double.valueOf(textBoxMiles.getText().toString());

                    double vKm = vMiles / 0.62317;

                    DecimalFormat formatVal = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                    textBoxKm.setText(formatVal.format(vKm));
            }
        });
```

**UPdate**

after going through the comment I implemented like this

```
  buttonConvertMilesToKm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        EditText textBoxMiles = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMiles);
        EditText textBoxKm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextKm);

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Double vMiles = Double.valueOf(textBoxMiles.getText().toString());
            //boolean x = android.text.TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(CharSequence Double.valueOf(textBoxMiles.getText().toString()));
            //if(vMiles.isNaN()) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(textBoxMiles.getText().toString())){
                double vKm = vMiles / 0.62317;

                DecimalFormat formatVal = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                textBoxKm.setText(formatVal.format(vKm));

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You did not enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }

        }
    });
```

Still its Crashing if the text field is Empty
It works fine if entered right value ,

I am new to android can y any one help me out

Thanks

Comment: dude use try/catch to check for number format (that is how java is supposed to be done), your edit will still crash if it gets bad formatting

Comment: Just move  `Double vMiles = Double.valueOf(textBoxMiles.getText().toString());` inside `if(!TextUtils.())`

Comment: @DeadpoolDude Bro tried your code block still crashing when Its empty

Comment: @Vikram I have edited the answer try the new version

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @MD did that still it crashes and I think its going inside infinity loop

Comment: becox `textBoxMiles ==null`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your EditText:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

also don't forget to check whether it is empty or not before setting text like this:

```
textBoxMiles.getText().toString().equals("")
```

inside if condition like this:

```
if(textBoxMiles.getText().toString().equals("")) {
 //empty 
}else {
 //not empty do something
}
```

and change this line:

```
Double vMiles = Double.valueOf(textBoxMiles.getText().toString());
```

to:

```
Double vMiles = Double.parseDouble(textBoxMiles.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thats the problem I am not able to check if its empty , I already have this in My XML tag

Comment: And why can't he simply catch the exception? @NongthonbamTonthoi what happens if his EditText is filled and in wrong format?

Answer (score -2):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String textMiles = textBoxMiles.getText().toString();
    if (!textMiles.trim().equals("")) {
        try {
            double vMiles = Double.parseDouble(textMiles);
            double vKm = vMiles / 0.62317;
            DecimalFormat formatVal = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
            textBoxKm.setText(formatVal.format(vKm));        
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // alternative action
        }
    } else {
        // alternative action
    }
}
```